# Why does my Babel import not work?

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs

my-module.js

```
function cube(x) {
  return x * x * x;
}
const foo = Math.PI + Math.SQRT2;
export { cube, foo };
```

app.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {cube} from './my-module';
```

console.log(cube(2));
No error , but shows, it seems that `import` is not working.  `stackoverflow`,no more details needed , the code has show my meaning, please don't enforce us to add more details.

```
"ReferenceError: cube is not defined
    at eval (eval at 35 (http://localhost:8080/build/bundle.js:84:1), <anonymous>:1:1)
    at Object.35 (http://localhost:8080/build/bundle.js:84:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:8080/build/bundle.js:20:30)
    at Object.34 (http://localhost:8080/build/bundle.js:71:18)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:8080/build/bundle.js:20:30)
    at http://localhost:8080/build/bundle.js:63:18
    at http://localhost:8080/build/bundle.js:66:10"
```

webpack.config.js

```
module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loaders: ['babel-loader'],
        exclude: /(node_modules)/
      },
```

.babelrc

```
{
  "presets": [
    "es2015",
    "react",
    "stage-0"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "transform-react-jsx"
  ],
  "retainLines": true,
  "sourceMaps": "both",
  "ignore": [
    "*.css"
  ]
}
```

Comment: `babelrc` not `bablerc`

Comment: also its `import { cube } from './my-module'`

Comment: @azium, hi, the line `import React from 'react'`  also shows `React` not defined.
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `import { cube } from './my-module'`

When you do `import cube` you are looking for the default export

Comment: still not working,  the line `import React from 'react'`  also shows `React` not defined.

Comment: you are right, The Chrome browser says `React ` is not defined , actually it defined ,  It seems that even though I add a breakpoint to the line `import {cube} from './my-module';` , we can't use  chrome console to see what the `React`  is .

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce the error with the infos that you provided but I couldn't.

Specifically I created this simple project and everything works as expected.

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "dummy-react",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "webpack": "^3.10.0"
  }
}
```

**.babelrc**

```
{
  "presets": [
    "es2015",
    "react",
    "stage-0"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "transform-react-jsx"
  ],
  "retainLines": true,
  "sourceMaps": "both",
  "ignore": [
    "*.css"
  ]
}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
var webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
  entry: './app.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loaders: ['babel-loader'],
        exclude: /(node_modules)/
      }
   ]
  }
}
```

**my-module.js**

```
function cube(x) {
  return x * x * x;
}
const foo = Math.PI + Math.SQRT2;
export { cube, foo };
```

**app.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import {cube} from './my-module'

console.log(cube(2))

ReactDOM.render(
  <h1>Hello, World!</h1>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
     <div id="root"></div>
     <script src="./bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

So probably the problem is not in the code that you provided.